# MiniProfiler not showing the profiling information overlay when running Web Forms application with Entity Framework database first

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, mvc-mini-profiler

I have been following the setup shown on

> http://miniprofiler.com/

I am referencing the `EntityFramework v4.3.1` NuGet Package in my Web Application just to get `MiniProfiler` working but the EF `.edmx` and generated model is in a separate referenced project.

I am also using

```
MiniProfile.EF v2.1.0
MiniProfiler v2.1.0
```

My web applications `global.asax.cs` looks like this

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
        //MiniProfilerEF.InitializeEF42();

        // Code that runs on application startup
        InitProfilerSettings();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            MiniProfiler.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }


    private void InitProfilerSettings()
    {
        // some things should never be seen
        var ignored = MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths.ToList();
        ignored.Add("/Styles/");
        ignored.Add("/Scripts/");
        ignored.Add("/files/");
        ignored.Add("/images/");
        MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths = ignored.ToArray();

        MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter();
    }

}
```

I have added a handler into my `web.config` as shown below

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <handlers>
        <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have added the below to my Master page at the end before closing the body tag

```
<%= StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
```

I could only setup a context with a profiled connection by doing the below , because otherwise I was getting a runtime error when using an `EntityConnection` during the execution of a LINQ query on the DBContext.

```
         //var _modelContext = new Entities();
        // ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString
        //var profiledConnection = new EFProfiledDbConnection(new Entities().Connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
        var profiledConnection = new EFProfiledDbConnection(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EntitiesSql"].ConnectionString), MiniProfiler.Current);
        var _modelContext = ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<Entities>(profiledConnection);
```

All of this seems to work and I can run my application locally and I can view the page source and see this script block, and in Chrome I can select the include.js link and see the contents

```
<script async type="text/javascript" id="mini-profiler" src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-version="xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/" data-current-id="adf7a5f4-482d-4f65-b09e-e3c59b157134" data-ids="adf7a5f4-482d-4f65-b09e-e3c59b157134" data-position="left" data-trivial="false" data-children="false" data-max-traces="15" data-controls="false" data-authorized="true" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-start-hidden="false"></script>
```

however when viewing the Console in Chrome I get the message of

```
POST http://localhost:54406/mini-profiler-resources/results 404 (Not Found)
```

I was hoping the addition of the relevant handler would have fixed my problem :( but it hasn't.

Any help is appreciated.